# Python - List of lists of different lengths

Tags: python, arrays, list

I need to create a list which contains two lists.
Something like

```
biglist = [list1,list2]
```

with

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6,7,8]
```

where `list1` and `list2` have DIFFERENT length and are imported from file.

I did it the following way:

```
biglist = []
list1 = #...taken from file. I checked this and it poduces a list exactly how I want it to be: [1,2,3]
biglist.append(list1)
```

and likewise for `list2`

but the problem is that I get

```
biglist = [array([1,2,3]),array([4,5,6,7,8])]
```

as opposed to

```
biglist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8]]
```

and I really don't want the `array` thing, I prefer to have simple lists.
how to get around this?

Comment: It seems that your `list1` and `list2` are numpy arrays. You can do this first:
`list1 = list.tolist()`  `list2 = list2.tolist()` and then append them to your big list

Comment: use extend instead of append

Comment: Please show the code where you parse the list from the file, because it is in that code that your list is parsed as a numpy array rather than a python list.

Answer (score 4):

please try:

```
biglist.append(list(list1))
biglist.append(list(list2))
```

or if they are numpy arrays

```
biglist.append(list1.tolist())
biglist.append(list2.tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it's a good answer and it's a plus one :)

Answer (score 3):

Just convert your `list1` and `list2` (those are confusing  names indeed because those are numpy arrays, just a comment) with `numpy.ndarray.tolist()` method and that's it

```
biglist = [list1.tolist(), list2.tolist()]
```

Comment: tolist? what python version is that?

Comment: there's no such method for lists

Comment: It exists for `numpy.array` types

Comment: @ᴬᴶᵁᴾᴾᴬᴸ I think the asker made it clear that the two objects are lists

Comment: @Mokshyam no the OP didn't. Just because the variable name has "list" in it doesn't make it a list. If you look at the latter part of the post, the lists are shown as `array([1,2,3])`. This is a `numpy.array`, not a list.

Comment: @user1767754 I modified the answer, I didn't clarify that the names wasn't the best, list1 is not a list is a npArray :), thanks for comment

Comment: @Mokshyam You are absolutely right, that's why I added in the edit of my answer, that I was talking about npArrays, not python list, even if the name of variables are list1, they are array, not list

Comment: @ᴬᴶᵁᴾᴾᴬᴸ thanks so much for helping me clarify my answer you rules :)

Answer (score 1):

- To create a list with all elements: `new_list = list1 + list2`
- To create a list with two lists inside: `new_list = [list1, list2]`

I think you want the second solution. Notice that a list can contain other datatypes inside. A list can contain `["string", 10, ["another", "list"], a_variable, more_stuff]` so creating a new list with more lists inside is easy. Just put each of your desired objects as an item.

**Update**: I don't know if this would work (never used numpy before) but is worth to try:

```
new_list = [list(str(list1)[6:-1]), list(str(list2)[6:-1])]
```

Comment: `list1` and `list2` are imported, so when he does this, `biglist ` has the array things that he does not want. That's the issue

Comment: Oh, I see now, that's tricky. The only fix that comes into my mind is.. I will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your `biglist` is a list of `numpy array` . So, 
convert `numpy array` to `list` by this way getting your desired output.

> np.array(list_name).tolist()

```
new_biglist = []
for ls in biglist:
    new_biglist.append(ls.tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are potential **two** ways to approach this:

**Native** Function: `list(object)`

```
   biglist = [list(list1), list(list2)]
```

**Numpy** Function: `numpy.ndarray.tolist()`

```
   bigList = [list1.tolist(), list2.tolist()]
```

While the question doesn't ask for an optimal method, but here are additional 2 cents to evaluate the **two** potential approach. Here, we can design test cases to evaluate the performance of each approach.

```
import timeit

def test1():
    bigList = [list(list1), list(list2)]

def test2():
    bigList = [list1.tolist(), list2.tolist()]

timeit.timeit(stmt=t1, number=1000)
timeit.timeit(stmt=t2, number=1000)
```

The output of `timeit` operation:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=t1, number=1000)
0.0024030208587646484

>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=t2, number=1000)
0.0007460117340087891``
```